# How to split string in chars and get code of each char in freemarker?

Tags: casting, char, freemarker

I think that I can split using this:

```
<#list str as c>
    ...
</#list>
```

But then I need to convert this char to byte and add it to another number. In most languages it will be like so:

```
int num=53, res;
char c='g';
res=num+c;//c cast to byte and then to int.
```

But I have no idea, how to do this.

P.S. I can't modify code, I only can add html pages, so I have to use freemarker for my logic.

Comment: What for do you need to do such "character arithmetic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add numbers to characters in FreeMarker out-of-the-box. The closest thing is `num?lower_abc` (and `n?upper_abc`), which converts 1 to `'a'`, 2 to `'b'`, and so on. If you can't solve the task with that, and you can't add Java classes either, then this is going to be  problem...

Also, you can't `#list` a string like that, but like this:

```
<#list 0..<str?length as i>
    <#assign c = str[i]>
    ...
</#list>`.
```

Comment: `<#list 0..<str?length as i>` '<' symbol before str is a typo, or it is required?

So, will use a big switch function. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's not a typo, it's a range with exclusive end (`from ..< to`).

Comment: And I'm still interested in the use case. (Because maybe it's something that warrants adding such functionality to FM.)